# multiple tests Layers for cargo rust project

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, rust-cargo

I would like to implement multiple tests layers.

My project do a lot of stuff and tests are very long.

I would like to have quick tests implemented in CI.
For this purpose I just do a

```
#[test]
fn deploy_kubernetes_things_and_co(){
...
}
```

In case of validation of those tests, I run a cargo test `test --color always -- --ignored`
it runs all my "long tests"

```
#[test]
fn one_of_my_very_long_integration_test(){
...
}
```

but I would like to have a third layer of tests, maybe on the night...
How Can I manage to implement it ?
I already read the rust/cargo documentation, I don't see anything else.

- Maybe I should create a lib tests called every nights ?

Comment: you can do it with features: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583049/run-additional-tests-by-using-a-feature-flag-to-cargo-test